# Pointers are pointing to Null despite allocation

Tags: c, pointers

I am in a function the problem parts have commented on them here i am.

```
int search(double startpos, double stepsize, double *res){
//Counter this will just make sure the algorithm doesn't search forever.
int i1 = 0;

//This will store results.
    res = (double *)calloc(2,sizeof(double));  //Here I am 
double *q = (double *)calloc(2,sizeof(double)); //This one too


q[0] = startpos;
q[1] = startpos + stepsize;

while((!compside(q[0],q[1], 1000)) && i1 < 100/stepsize){
    //keep going until we find a root
    q[0] +=stepsize;
    q[1] += stepsize;
    i1++;
}
    //determine whether a root was found or not.
    if(i1>=(100/stepsize))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Originally I just had `res = calloc(2, sizeof(double));` and all the `q`s were `res`s. But what's happening is that when I run gdb it tells me that res is pointing at null (`0x0`) and that `q` is pointing correctly at the array.

I have a few questions:

1. Why do I need a cast on the `calloc`? It should be returning a `void *` pointer and it doesn't make sense, `q` doe not point to the heap allocation when the cast is removed! Why?
   I know that it should be implicitly converted to `double *`.
2. Why is `res` pointing at `null` it is a double pointer yet no matter what I do it just doesn't point at the heap I have allocated for it?

Comment: You don't need to cast the result of `calloc`. Your claim that cast changes the value of `q` is unrealistic. The same applies to `res`. You need to provide more details about what you are doing, like at what point exactly you are checking `res`.

Comment: I think you checked value of res outside this function. To change the pointer (not value of the pointer) you should declare the function like: `int search(..., double** res)` because you want to change the pointer not value of the pointer and in coude you should writer `*res = (double*)calloc(2,sizeof(double))`

Comment: Did you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer to your questions:

1. You don't need to cast the return of `calloc()`, `malloc()` and friends. They return a `void *`. Actually it may be harmful to do so.
2. In your code `res` can only be NULL if `calloc()` can't allocate memory which is rather uncommon unless you are on an embedded system. However if you are checking `res` in the calling function, it will be unchanged (i.e. if it was NULL, it still is).

If your intention was to return the memory allocated to the caller function, then you should have passed a `double **` like this:

```
int caller ()
{
   double *val = NULL;
   int rc = 0;
   ...
   rc = called(&val)
   ...
   // Always, always free the memory! (unless you know what you're doing)
   free(val); 
   return rc;
}


int called(double **v)
{
  double *r;
  int c = 0;
  r = calloc(2,sizeof(double));
  if (r) {
    r[0] = ...;
    r[1] = ...;
    c = ...;
  }
  *v = r; // Now the return from calloc() is actually stored in the
          // variable val in the scope of the function caller()

  return c;
}
```

Also, you don't do anything with the memory pointed by res and that value will be lost when the function returns, either you don't need it or you missed to assign something.

Last thing: as it is now (with no `free()`) the memory you have allocated with `calloc()` will be returned to the system only after your program ends.